# Facebook friends returning empty data

Tags: flutter, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

I implemented possibility to search friends from facebook who logged into my app using facebook.

It was working, I was getting one facebook id as I supposed, but now I trying to work about functionalities around this and I am getting empty data. I even check with other friend but still data for friends is empty. Something changed in last month?

```
{
  "id": "49....38",
  "name": "Karol Wiśniewski",
  "friends": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 359
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: Yes, I have people who logged in using facebook to my app in friends

Comment: Did those friends also grant your app `user_friends` permission? Otherwise, your app will not be able to see them.

Comment: Yes, during logging in.

Comment: How long ago were they last active in your app? It might be an issue of Data Access Expiration, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/auth-vs-data#data-access-expiration

Comment: I yesterday installed app and logged in using facebook on my friend phone